# Cell Spanning in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am trying to create a weekly calendar that will show a scrollable list of events for each day of the week. I previously asked a question about getting everything to line up, and got a comment to just use a tableview. Now I am having the issue of row spanning. Depending on the length of the given event, the event may need to span one row or twenty. I keep seeing things that cell spanning has been removed, but is there any decent way to accomplish this? [Here is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW5qM.png)

Comment: I don't think what you are looking for is possible with a tableview.  You likely need to spend time looking at Canvas.  Or check this out if you are looking for a commercial product. http://dlsc.com/products/calendarfx/

Comment: @purring, I really don't want to have to use third party APIs, I'd rather create my own if it's absolutely necessary. Do you know of any other objects that may work better for cell spanning? GridPane hasn't worked too well so far

Comment: What is exactly your problem with the GridPane implementation? From my point of view using a GridPane is a proper approach. Having a look at my wall calendar you could use a 6 row (1 row as the header row and 5 weeks) and 8 column (1 column for the week number (could be configurable) and 7 columns for the days). Then you could use, if necessary for too many events, Scrollable areas in a cell. You can experiment with the max/min or dynamic sizing height of the cells to have a good looking layout.

Comment: @SSchuette, please take a look at my [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050487/how-can-i-make-the-contents-of-a-scrollpane-continue-behind-the-scrollbar) to see my original problem. GridPane was working for me at first, but having it inside a scrollPane to be able to scroll threw off the alignment of the columns

Comment: Perhaps a `TableView` in a `StackPane` with the calendar events represented as colored rectangles overlaid on the `TableView`.  The calendar events' dimensions and positioning could be set using bound properties.